# how to access sitemap.xml file out side in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{storeId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String mainStoreDeals(final ModelMap model, final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable final String storeId) throws IOException, BaseDataException {
    model.addAttribute("storeId", storeId);
    model.addAttribute(STORE, "store_products");
    return "storeproducts";
}
```

Some code I'm using in my spring mvc.

I pasted sitemap.xml file into my root

but once I tried to access its calling above controller.

I need both should be work is any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what @Predrag Maric is saying, if you're not generating the file dynamically, you can simply add a config to serve it as a static resource, so simply

```
<resources mapping="/sitemap.xml" location="/" />
```

or the equivalent java config if you're not using xml

Answer (score 0):

You could add another controller method for serving `sitemap.xml`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sitemap.xml", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

If you put `sitemap.xml` in your classpath instead of app root, then you can access it using `new ClassPathResource("sitemap.xml")` and flush it into the response.